# Disabling specific cell edit in DataGrid

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I need to know is it possible to disable a specific cell edit in a DataGrid, **without** disabling edit for the entire column in Silverlight 4. I can get the specific cell object as a FrameworkElement but it does not contain property IsReadOnly or IsEnabled. 
You will probably ask: Why do I need that? Well my application requires disabling particular cells in row depending on the other cell content. Each row is being checked this way separately.
If you have an idea how I can achieve such a unusual behaviour please write ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the row,column index of the cell/cells that you wish to have disabled:

```
int r = 2, c = 4;
```

Then you can listen to the events CellEnter and CellLeave and do the following:

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == r)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == c)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.RowIndex == r)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == c)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

You're still setting the entire column to Readonly, but since you are resetting it back after you leave the cell it has the effect of appearing to only work for the cell.

Comment: I used a bit different approach. I hooked up to CurrentCellChanged event and CellEditEnded events of DataGrid. But the idea was really helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You don't know what **Boolean logic** is, do you?

Comment: It's bad practice to write code like `if(true){if(true){ x = y;}}`. It's written like `if(true && true){ x = y; }`.

Comment: @Nordvind I wrote the code like I did to **teach** the OP, not to write the best code. The question was fairly simple, and I didn't want to obfuscate the answer with anything the OP *might* not understand. If you are looking for "perfect" code in answers on SO then you're coming to the wrong place. This website is meant as a learning tool.

Comment: >I wrote the code like I did to teach the OP not to write the best code

 So you did it - you taught OP how to write 'not the best' code. Assuming that starters should write crap that's hard to read is just stupid, not to say more. If one's doing OOP and doesn't know what boolean logic is (it's taught in school) he/she should change his/her profession.

Comment: @Nordvind I find that it is best not to (in any way) obfuscate code when teaching someone something. You are of course welcome to disagree.

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsReadOnly Attribute for particular cell like this

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID"
                                        Binding="{Binding ID}"
                                        IsReadOnly="True"/>
```

I this this is best idea for disabling a specific cell.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks NominSim, This helps me me to solve my proplem too, but as neurotix
didnt find CellEnter and CellLeave methods on my DataGrid in SilverLight 4.

As NominSim said, you need to know the index of row and the column.

How i solve it:

**Disable editing**

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timMakeEditable = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();

  private void dataGrid1_PreparingCellForEdit(object sender, DataGridPreparingCellForEditEventArgs e)
{
    timMakeEditable.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100); // 100 Milliseconds 
    timMakeEditable.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
    timMakeEditable.Start();

    if (e.RowIndex == r && e.ColumnIndex == c)
    {
            dataGrid1.Columns[yourColumnIndex].IsReadOnly = true;     
    }
}
```

**Enable editing**

After some milliseconds the timer make the column enabled:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGrid1.Columns[yourColumnIndex].IsReadOnly = false;
        timMakeEditable.Stop();  

    }
```

I think is a better idea use cellEditEnded, but it didnt work for me.