# Silverlight datagrid disable particular cell

Tags: .net, silverlight, validation, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

There must be a validation in silverlight's `DataGrid` element: if specific value is selected in combo-box, check-box column on the same row (`DataGridCheckBoxColumn`) must be disabled. However, from what I see, I can disable only the entire column, which is **unacceptable**.

So, how do I disable a particular cell if I have its coordinates (row, column)?

P.S. Similar question - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129336/disabling-specific-cell-edit-in-datagrid) doesn't suit for me. There are **no CellEnter and CellLeave events** in silverlight 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A part of the answer may be:

```
private void DisableCheckboxColumnInRow(DataGridRow row)
{
    var checkBoxColumn = Datagrid1.Columns[0];
    var checkBoxCell = GetCell(checkBoxColumn, row);
    checkBoxCell.IsEnabled = false;
}

private static DataGridCell GetCell(DataGridColumn column, DataGridRow row)
{
    var cellContent = column.GetCellContent(row);
    return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;
}
```

But there may me a better way to do this using MVVM:

ViewModel part:

```
public class TestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isChecked;
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return _isChecked; }
        set
        {
            _isChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
        }
    }

    private bool _canBeChecked;
    public bool CanBeChecked
    {
        get { return _canBeChecked; }
        private set
        {
            _canBeChecked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CanBeChecked");
        }
    }

    private string _selectedValue;
    public string SelectedValue
    {
        get { return _selectedValue; }
        set
        {
            _selectedValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedValue");
            // here we do the 'magic':
            CanBeChecked = SelectedValue != "one";
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> PossibleValues
    {
        get
        {
            yield return "one";
            yield return "two";
            yield return "free";
        }
    }

    #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

View part:

```
<Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleValues}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedValue,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
<Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanBeChecked}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</Controls:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```